# Form of intros in Coq specifically for `forall` and explicitly for `->`

Tags: coq, tactic

Are there tactics in Coq that are more limited versions (subtactics?) of `intros`?

I'm curious if there are any specifically for `forall ...` and specifically for `->`.

---

`intros` in Coq is capable of undoing the outermost `forall` as well as the outermost `->`.

It introduces hypotheses with provided or arbitrary names.

I suspect the reason for this generality is the fact that `coq` is built on top of the calculus of inductive constructions and `forall` and `->` really are both special cases of the dependent $\Pi$-type. (Also, now that I think about it, `forall` might actually *be* the general construction. I'm not sure.)

Here is an example from the `Basics.v` file from Software Foundations. This is a theorem and proof provided by authors, not a completed exercise from SF. (I mention this because the authors ask people not to post solutions to SF problems online.)

```
Theorem plus_id_example : forall n m:nat,
  n = m ->
  n + n = m + m.

Proof.
  (* move both quantifiers into the context: *)
  intros n m.
  (* move the hypothesis into the context: *)
  intros H.
  (* rewrite the goal using the hypothesis: *)
  rewrite -> H.
  reflexivity.  Qed.
```

Anyway, the generality of `intros` is nice in theory, but it can make tactic scripts harder to read. Are there weaker tactics than `intros` that can only unpack `->` or only unpack `forall`? That would make it easier to tell at a glance what roughly what "part" of a theorem is being addressed by a tactic appearing in the middle of a tactic script.

Comment: `forall (x : nat), 1 = 1` is equal to `nat -> 1 = 1`. So how would that tactic behave in this case?

Comment: @Trebor I would treat that as an instance of `forall` because the type of the bound variable isn't `Prop`. But your point is well taken. Whether a `forall`/`->`/$\Pi$ ignores its bound variable or not is completely orthogonal to what type the bound variable has. I guess this question doesn't really make sense since there's no principled way to distinguish "uses that look like $\to$ in logic" and "uses that look like $\forall$ in logic", which is what I was really trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Your question has two interpretations. You can make a tactic that *rejects* bad usages; you can also use two alias of the same tactic, and use them in a principled, but *unenforced* way.

Comment: Those are both interesting and I don't know how to do either. I'm primarily interested in rejecting bad usages, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`intros *` only unpacks `forall`. [Example from the reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#intropattern-star-ex):

```
    ============================
    forall A B : Prop, A -> B

intros *.
      
    A, B : Prop
    ============================
    A -> B
```